# Why proxy don't work for local network?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

We have a stage server running in local network, that could be accessed from the internet. I want to test gdpr, and set proxy in browser, so ip checker sites shows my new ip. But when I access our stage server, it shows my local ip. Why does it happen? How to access it through proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out our stage server sits under NAT, and when traffic comes though it user ip get changed to local gateway. And eventually  nginx that get ip and set x-forwarded-for header, always set local ip.